# Equivocation crash (network with ~100 Aura Validators)

Tags: grandpa, stalled

We've had a test network running for about 3.5 months with regularly-rotating sets of Aura / Grandpa Validators.

Suddenly, we have run into an issue whereby the vast majority (~2/3) of the network has crashed due to an error in the node software which references equivocation:

```
2022-04-03 01:57:10 ⛓  Native runtime: chainflip-node-111 (chainflip-node-1.tx1.au1)
2022-04-03 01:57:10 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2022-04-03 01:57:10  Local node identity is: 12D3KooWQbTk1xVSvp8YM3p8uoJrjSa3LKL2UBt11Excd1i11spW
2022-04-03 01:57:10  Highest known block at #1502697
2022-04-03 01:57:10 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
2022-04-03 01:57:10 Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9944.
2022-04-03 01:57:10 Detected precommit equivocation in the finality worker: Equivocation { round_number: 16286, identity: Public(72198707e967f3eafcc44437c15feaacfee9c29059958559ae85fdf7a2b5a854 (5EeJu7Mc...)), first: (Precommit { target_hash: 0xdebdc23f58d523fc1030ed688ed08aaf252dc71b298b024ba254e39c1713c9fd, target_number: 1502695 }, Signature(718a0d6598ae2467fd8b14cdf45862de76cb312b451653573bc8878cd617a99fe87ee3acb20391aa1aaae95b3ca5c22064e33b68e1ddf33e5732e2aa2cc7f905)), second: (Precommit { target_hash: 0x455b67971ddd25a36f132d1b8cf283147f9250c4c0aaf657b538142bf08cc88b, target_number: 1502694 }, Signature(9e9fa86949ccd8e0b909c0e573f494ce2fd3e1794c1d3adacb426d9393ced247b51e9686f455676ecaf6cfd4f58759cf7366f193f8e1d0579268f033aa17eb00)) }
2022-04-03 01:57:11 GRANDPA voter error: Client(BadJustification("invalid precommits for target commit"))
2022-04-03 01:57:11 Essential task `grandpa-voter` failed. Shutting down service.
Error: Service(Other("Essential task failed."))
```

I understand that this might happen if 1/3 of the Authority Set had misconfigured Validators sending duplicate Grandpa votes. I find that hard to believe but I'm willing to investigate further if this is the most likely cause.

I have a few more questions though:

- What is the Public identity which is reported in this log message? I can't find it in any of our logs, which would indicate that it is not a public identifier that we're ever referencing (ie, it doesn't show up in the Polkajs interface). Is it referring to a particular Session key? How would I find the Aura ID of this identifier such that I can ask for the logs from this machine?
- Does Aura have different equivocation conditions to Babe?
- How can we recover from this scenario? We're currently attempting to re-sync our nodes from one of the Validators which is still online, is this the correct approach? Finality is stalled but it looks like block production is still ongoing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Aura - only Grandpa cares about equivocations. I expect the Public identity being referred to is the Grandpa key of the misbehaving node. A text search through all validators' session keys should turn it up (but since session keys are just several concatenated keys, it will likely be in the middle somewhere).

An equivocation should not result in the node terminating. It should be reported and punished. You should open an issue in the Substrate GH repo and report with whatever logs you have. The team will likely ask for more detailed logs.

Comment: Thanks Gav, I will do that.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple public identities reported in the log message that you provided.

The node identity `Local node identity is: 12D3KooWQbTk1xVSvp8YM3p8uoJrjSa3LKL2UBt11Excd1i11spW` that is shown in your logs may have been automatically generated if you did not specify a value for the `--node-key` option when running your validator node, which you can manually generate using `subkey generate-node-key --file node-key` https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/integrate/subkey#generating-node-keys, which generates a public peer bootnode ID (node ID) like the value `12D3KooWQbTk1xVSvp8YM3p8uoJrjSa3LKL2UBt11Excd1i11spW` shown in your logs, and it adds an associated secret Node Key to a file named 'node-key' and you specify that as the value of `--node-key <GENERATED_NODE_KEY>` when starting your validator.

Another public identity mentioned in your logs is the authority id of the equivocator (offender) that it detected as being the precommit equivocation finality worker `identity: Public(72198707e967f3eafcc44437c15feaacfee9c29059958559ae85fdf7a2b5a854 (5EeJu7Mc...))`, and it shows the round number `round_number` when that equivocation happened.

If you use Subkey and prefix that address with `0x`, you can reveal the full SS58 Address:

```bash
$ subkey inspect --public --scheme Sr25519 0x72198707e967f3eafcc44437c15feaacfee9c29059958559ae85fdf7a2b5a854
Network ID/version: substrate
  Public key (hex):   0x72198707e967f3eafcc44437c15feaacfee9c29059958559ae85fdf7a2b5a854
  Account ID:         0x72198707e967f3eafcc44437c15feaacfee9c29059958559ae85fdf7a2b5a854
  SS58 Address:       5EeJu7McQLXjVxWKfUWqYsBbB6oHDEPNcPpv6dununkMq74J
```

There are two more public identities in your logs that are the signatures of votes that are used to verify the precommit equivocation proof.

```
first: (Precommit { target_hash: 0x<BLOCK_HASH_X>, target_number: <BLOCK_NO_X> }, Signature(<SIGNATURE_VOTER_1>)),
second: (Precommit { target_hash: 0x<BLOCK_HASH_Y>, target_number: <BLOCK_NO_Y> }, Signature(<SIGNATURE_VOTER_2>)) }
```

In the Substrate implementation it says outgoing message votes to the network by authorities may be replaced depending on whether or not they have voted, and the votes are *"stored unsigned"*. It says this means the *"signatures need to be "stable"*, and that this is currently true for `Ed25519` signatures, and that *"care must be taken when switching to different key types"*.

I wonder if you the issue you encountered was generated because your validators are using Grandpa session keys that were generated using the default Sr25519 cryptography scheme instead of Ed25519? For example to generate a Grandpa session key for your first validator using Subkey with Ed25519 (instead of the Subkey's default Sr25519 cryptography scheme) you could run `subkey inspect --scheme=ed25519 "$SECRET//1//grandpa"`, where `$SECRET` is your Secret Key URI.

If that is the cause then you could try removing the old Grandpa session keys and generating and inserting new Grandpa session keys for all validators using the Ed25519 cryptography scheme.

Comment: Thanks Luke! I'm confused about the identity of the equivocator. I can't find that account on our chain anywhere. Is this because it's not necessarily the identity which would correspond to a Validator's balance? As for inserting / rotating session keys, we use a standardised CLI tool for each Validator which calls the `rotate_keys()` RPC on their own node, and then submits the new keys (Aura is the first 32 bytes and Grandpa the last 32, right?) with an extrinsic. We don't ask Validators to use Subkey to generate these keys.

Comment: could someone else have run a validator on your chain? it shows here https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-kusama#option-2-cli that the `author_rotateKeys` RPC calls Substrate's `rotate_keys` function and outputs a hex-encoded "result" field that is the concatenation of the four public keys, but in the Substrate implementation they don't appear to sort them in any specific order. perhaps try providing `"params":["KEY_TYPE", "SEED", "PUBLIC"]` in the `author_insertKey` RPC calls to set them individually key by key.

Comment: Running a Validator on our chain is a semi-permissioned process. It's not difficult to meet the requirements, though we do enforce certain conditions. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "could someone else have run a validator on your chain?" It's a public testnet, so there are a bunch of different participants.

Comment: You already mentioned that you checked all logs I guess since genesis and there's no trace of those addresses. Maybe the logs don't show all keys associated with other validators that connected to your chain and maybe those other keys are the equivocator keys that you can't identify?

Comment: How would "another Validator connect to our chain" exactly? I'm a little in the dark about what you mean - could you elaborate? E.g. do they just connect directly to some IPs and start gossiping Grandpa messages on libp2p etc? We don't allow someone's Session keys to be rotated into Aura / Grandpa unless they meet some of our requirements. In any case it looks like a single Validator was able to effectively crash the chain, which is a showstopper for us.